# Oracle regexp, Find a number length of 3 in the beginnning, if the string begins with a number. Else, find number with 3 digit length at the end

Tags: oracle, regexp-replace

I have used a case statement, but still not working. How can I solve this.

```
WITH tst
AS
(
  SELECT '639 - xadfa dfdsa euwere (15-30Min)' str FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'AB/NCDSDFsd - 218' FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT '141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT 
  str,
  CASE 
    WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(SUBSTR(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '([^[:digit:] ])', '')),-3,3))) = 3        
    THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '([^[:digit:] ])', '')),-3,3))
    ELSE
     CASE 
      WHEN LENGTH(TRIM(SUBSTR(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '([^[:digit:] ])', '')),1,3))) = 3
      THEN TRIM(SUBSTR(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(str, '([^[:digit:] ])', '')),1,3))
      ELSE NULL
    END
  END num_val
FROM tst;
```

Query Result:

```
   STR                                  NUM_VAL
   --------------------------------------------
   141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3       141
   639 - xadfa dfdsa euwere (15-30Min)  530
   AB/NCDSDFsd - 218                    218
```

If the string begins with a 3 consecutive digit set, then i need that first 3 digit set. If the string begins with a letter, then i need the 3 digit set at the end of the string.
   Expected Output:

```
   STR                                  NUM_VAL
   --------------------------------------------
   141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3       141
   639 - xadfa dfdsa euwere (15-30Min)  639
   AB/NCDSDFsd - 218                    218
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question to explain what you are trying to do? From the title is spunds like you want the last set of exactly three consecutive digits in the string, maybe?

Comment: What should be returned from `'141 - some stuff - 3920 - blah blah'`? Is 141 a three-digit number, 3920 a four-digit number, so return 141? Or return 920 (the last sequence of three consecutive digits in the input)? Or something else?

Comment: If the string begins with a 3 consecutive digit set, then i need that first 3 digit set. If the string begins with a letter, then i need the 3 digit set at the end of the string.

Comment: Always expect the unexpected!  What if the string starts with a special character? Starts with a letter but ends with a 4 digit number?  Has no number?  Is a NULL string?  Provide some exceptions to test with and how they are expected to be handled as well.  A correct solution has to handle it all. Don't wait until code is in production before the surprises are found!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reformulated problem can be solved, for example, as follows:

```
WITH tst
AS
(
  SELECT '639 - xadfa dfdsa euwere (15-30Min)' str FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'AB/NCDSDFsd - 218'                       FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'dsafas 123 COMP - 751'                   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3'          FROM DUAL
)
select str, regexp_substr(str, '(^\d{3}|\d{3}$)') as num
from   tst;

STR                                 NUM                                
----------------------------------- -------------------
639 - xadfa dfdsa euwere (15-30Min) 639                
AB/NCDSDFsd - 218                   218
dsafas 123 COMP - 751               751                
141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3      141
```

The regular expression is an alternation. `^` and `$` are anchors - they require the fragment to be at the beginning, respectively at the end of the input string. `( ... | ... )` means find the first alternative, and if not found, then find the second alternative. `\d{3}` means exactly 3 digits.

Comment: thanks @mathguy.. This looks to be a perfect solution. I really appreciate your earlier comments, yes i do agree a solution should handle all the situations.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question this would be a solution:

```
WITH tst
AS
(
  SELECT '639 - xadfa dfdsa 456 euwere (15-30Min)' str FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT 'AB/NCDSDFsd - 218' FROM DUAL
  UNION
  SELECT '141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3' FROM DUAL
)
select str,
   regexp_substr(str, '[[:digit:]]{3}', 1, regexp_count(str, '[[:digit:]]{3}')) as num_val
from tst;


STR                                          NUM_VAL 
-------------------------------------------  -----------
141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3               141
639 - xadfa dfdsa 456 euwere (15-30Min)      456
AB/NCDSDFsd - 218                            218
```

Comment: The OP needs to clarify the requirement. The solution you offer will return 394 from the input `'141 something 39458 something'` - very unlikely that `'394'` would be the last occurrence of a three-digit number in the string. If anything, that would be `'458'`.

Answer (score 0):

**Use of non-greedy quantifier between digits and end anchor or ....the reverse function**

I use a non-greedy quantifier approach (line 23), but it seems to work primarily because the first quantifier is greedy.

I use anchors to match the entire string. I place the match "non-end of line character", ., in a subexpression and use the non-greedy quantifier at the end of the string, *? (zero or more).

Non-greedy quantifiers do not always work in Oracle 12.1 (which I am using).

Plan b would be just use the reverse function 2x (line 24).

```
SCOTT@db>WITH tst AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          '141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3 141 639 - xadfa dfdsa euwere (15-30Min) 639 AB/NCDSDFsd - 2184 4  5' smple
  4      FROM
  5          dual
  6      UNION ALL
  7      SELECT
  8          '639 - xadfa dfdsa euwere (15-30Min)'
  9      FROM
 10          dual
 11      UNION ALL
 12      SELECT
 13          'AB/NCDSDFsd - 218'
 14      FROM
 15          dual
 16      UNION ALL
 17      SELECT
 18          '141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3'
 19      FROM
 20          dual
 21  ) SELECT
 22      smple,
 23      regexp_substr(smple,'^(.)*(\d{3})(.)*?$',1,1,NULL,2) nongreedy,
 24      reverse(regexp_substr(reverse(smple),'(\d{3})',1,1,NULL,1) ) rev_fun
 25    FROM
 26      tst;
SMPLE                                                                                                NONGREEDY   REV_FUN
141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3                                                                       141         141
141 - Uxsdfasd Zebasdased ABC3 141 639 - xadfa dfdsa euwere (15-30Min) 639 AB/NCDSDFsd - 2184 4  5   184         184
639 - xadfa dfdsa euwere (15-30Min)                                                                  639         639
AB/NCDSDFsd - 218                                                                                    218         218
```